# Prove that for any infinite set $A$, $|\mathbb{N}|\le |A|$

Tags: cardinals

How can you show that for any infinite set $A$, $|\mathbb{N}|\le |A|$?

thanks

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917593/infinite-set-has-greater-or-equal-cardinality-that-of-n

Comment: There are plenty of other duplicates. If someone can be bothered to look for them.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow the axiom of dependent choice: Just choose distinct elements $a_0,a_1,\dotsc$ in $A$ recursively. This cannot end, since otherwise $A$ would be finite. Thus, $a : \mathbb{N} \to A$ is an injective function.

If you want to stay in ZF, this won't work. There is a difference between infinite sets and [Dedekind-infinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set) sets.